# Problem with Infinitest

Tags: eclipse, tdd, infinitest

I'm using infinitest the eclipse plug-in. but sometimes it just do not work.
I have a test for a method `a()`. The method `a()` calls method `b()` which calls method `c()`. if I change the method `b()` it runs the test for the method `a`. but it doesn't trigger if I change the method `c()`.

Comment: Sounds to me like it could be a bug in Infinitest's algorithm which decides which tests to run. Did you report it to them?

Answer (score 0):

Does `b()` always call `c()` or only sometimes?

Do you have tests that cover the scenarios where `c()` is called?